# YAML-Print string a number of times

Tags: python, string, ansible, yaml

Is there an easy way in `YAML` to print a string a number of times?

for example in `Python`

```
print('String' * 500)
```

Can't get the syntax working in `YAML`

Comment: If you check the documentation for ansible-playbooks they say about the usage of YAML: _...which intentionally tries to not be a programming language or script..._

Answer (score 0):

You can use below to print the string say 50 times :

```
- name: Print 50 times
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
      - name: with file
        debug: msg="This is my loop"
        with_sequence: count=50
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences)

Answer (score 0):

YAML ("YAML Ain't Markup Language") is a human-readable data-serialization language. It is commonly used for configuration files and in applications where data is being stored or transmitted.

Its not a programming language. So that I think you can solve your problem with Python's yaml library.

1. load YAM file as Python object
2. Update the value here ('String' * 500)
3. Dump Python object to YAML file.

https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-yaml-to-a-file-in-python/